# Manipulate JSON key values with one header row array and rest header values array for table

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I want to restructure the current JSON of `data` as shown below

```
   const data = [
      {
        "status": "Complete",
        "totalToday": 3,
        "weekly": 20
      },
      {
        "status": "Pending",
        "totalToday": 5,
        "weekly": 13
      },
      {
        "status": "Rejected",
        "totalToday": 2,
        "weekly": 5
      }
    ];
```

Expected output:

```
const newData = [
    ['Status', 'Total Today', 'Weekly'],
    ['Complete', 3, 20],
    ['Pending', 5, 13],
    ['Rejected', 2, 5]
];
```

Comment: Please also add your try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.forEach()`

```js
const data = [{
    "status": "Complete",
    "totalToday": 3,
    "weekly": 20
  },
  {
    "status": "Pending",
    "totalToday": 5,
    "weekly": 13
  },
  {
    "status": "Rejected",
    "totalToday": 2,
    "weekly": 5
  }
];
let transformedData = []
transformedData.push(Object.keys(data[0]).map(key => {
  return key.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
     .replace(/^./, (str) => str.toUpperCase())
}))
data.forEach(val => transformedData.push(Object.values(val)))
console.log(transformedData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method, in which you iterate over an `Array` of Object. On the `0` index, you can use `Object.keys()` to get the key and `Object.values` for the corresponding values and `push` it to the `accumulator`. For else you can iterate Object values and push it to the `accumulator` acc.

```js
const data = [
      {
        "status": "Complete",
        "totalToday": 3,
        "weekly": 20
      },
      {
        "status": "Pending",
        "totalToday": 5,
        "weekly": 13
      },
      {
        "status": "Rejected",
        "totalToday": 2,
        "weekly": 5
      }
    ];

const newData = data.reduce((acc, x, idx) => {
  if(idx === 0) {
    acc.push(Object.keys(x), Object.values(x));
  } else {
    acc.push(Object.values(x));
  }
  return acc;
}, [])


console.log(newData);
```